# Isabelle resolves interpretation

Tags: locale, isabelle, interpretation

I'm using Isabelle 2019 and got some troubles regarding locals:

I'm constructing a locale with an abbrevation, e.g.:

```
interpretation myInstance : myLocale "abbreviation"
```

I'm using this with a function from the locale, e.g.:

```
myInstance.getter myinput
```

But `apply simp` now "simplifies" the goal to something like this

```
myLocale.getter "abbreviation" myinput
```

How can I avoid simp to do this?
(I'm pretty sure, this is the reason, why my code takes ages to process)...

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2020-March/msg00019.html) and there is no perfect solution. Some partial solutions:

- live with it/avoid using something that can be simplified. Use a definition instead of an abbreviation (and eventually mark the definition as simp to automatically unfold it).
- add a congruence rule (as [mentioned](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2020-March/msg00019.html)): `⋀a b. myLocale.getter a b == myLocale.getter "abbreviation" myinput a b`. It does not always work.
- Define a new constant and lift all theorems to that constant. This is annoying (and can make sledgehammer less powerful).